# How would I convert a nested list into a string?

Tags: python, string, list, nested

I Would like to convert something such as this nested list

```
[['0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1'], 
['0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0'], 
['0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0'], 
['1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0'], 
['1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1'],
['1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0'], 
['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0'], 
['0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '2'], 
['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1'], 
['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1'], 
['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1'], 
['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1'], 
['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1'], 
['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1']]
```

into something like this:

```
[[0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
[0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0], 
[1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], 
[1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1], 
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0], 
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2], 
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

Thanks. If you show me all the lines needed for this conversion I will be forever greatful

Comment: I'm confused, your code example question does not match your title. Are you trying to convert the strings into ints? Cuz that's what your input/output example shows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let the list_of_list b you can simply try `int()`

```
[[int(i) for i in j] for j in list_of_list]
```

in python you can convert `string digits` into integer using `int()`

you can also try

```
[map(int,j) for j in list_of_list]
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  I used your second option and it worked!!